# How do I fetch all the branches in git after cloning a repo in github, NEWB question

Tags: git, github

I am trying to learn git and its workflow & I want to ask if how do I fetch all the branches in git after cloning a project repo in github?

So my main focus is to learn collaborating with git and I am cloning a project repo in github with 2 branches in my main project.

this is my main repo's git branch result

[image]

and this is in my clone folder

[image]

I didn't get all the repository there , you see ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple (but subtly wrong, in multiple ways) answer is that you already have all the branches.

> I am trying to learn git and its workflow & I want to ask if how do I fetch all the branches in git after cloning a project repo in github?

As [tymtam said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58968529/1256452), you can just `git checkout` a name like `basic-feature` and  suddenly it's there.

This bit of magic is brought to you by what Git calls *DWIM mode*, where DWIM stands for Do What I Mean (as opposed to what you said).  If you ask Git to check out a branch *name* that you don't have yet—such as `basic-feature`—your Git will proceed to search through a second set of names, which are your Git's *remote-tracking names*.  On finding an appropriate match, `git checkout` will actually *create* the name for you, right on the spot.

To list your repository's remote-tracking names, use:

```
git branch --list --remote
```

which you can abbreviate to just:

```
git branch -r
```

(Note: if your Git is extremely old, it may have only the short form options.)

A remote-tracking name is a name like `origin/master` or `origin/basic-feature`.  When you clone some other repository, you give your Git a short name for that other repository.  You can choose a name, but the default one is `origin`.  This is called a *remote*.  The short name `origin` stands in for the longer URL that you entered (e.g., `https://github.com/path/to/repo.git`).

When your Git calls up the other Git, your Git gets, from the other Git, a list of all of *its* branch names.  Your Git then copies those names to your `origin/*` names—or some other prefix if you chose some other name instead of `origin`.  These are your *remote-tracking names*, which remember *their* Git's *branch* names.  (Git itself calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, but I find the extra word *branch* in here unhelpful.  These names act sort of like branch names, but enough different that I prefer to leave out the word *branch* now.)

There is a problem with Git's nomenclature here, because the word *branch* itself has multiple different meanings.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Sometimes we mean a *branch name*, sometimes we mean a *remote-tracking name*, and sometimes we mean *some collection of commits, probably found by using one of those names*.  You must infer from context which of these someone means, if they just say "a branch".

Note that while `git fetch` has this `--all` option, it means *all remotes*.  You can list out which remote names you have—likely just `origin`—using:

```
git remote
```

If you have more than one, `git fetch --all` will invoke `git fetch` on each one.  If, as usual, you only have one, `git fetch --all` will invoke `git fetch` on all one of them, and hence not do anything different from `git fetch` without `--all`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
git fetch --all
```

And then you check if it work or not

```
git branch -a
```

Comment: `git fetch --all` fetches from all *remotes*.

Comment: yes, that is. The owner topic needs this use case

Answer (score 1):

You cloned the whole repository.

All the branches are there.

You can confirm this with `git branch --all`.

Go on, check out `basic-feature`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch --all
```

or

```
git remote update
```

Remind that, `fetch` will not create or update local branches (which track remote branches); if you want to update your local branches you still need to pull every branch.

If you want to list all remote branches:

```
git branch -a
```

To update local branches which track remote branches:

```
git pull --all
```

Comment: Again, `--all` is not necessary. This option fetches from all *remotes*. You already get all branches by default, from *one* remote. If you have only one remote—as the OP does—fetching one remote *is* fetching from all.